# Find parameter in GRIB with iris

Tags: python-iris

New user of Iris here. I have loaded a GRIB file that has created a list of cubes, many of them have "unknown" name and units. In this list of cubes there should be the temperature at different model levels (perhaps in not all the cubes). Example of the first cube in the list:

```
unknown / (unknown)                 (--: 14; projection_y_coordinate: 469; projection_x_coordinate: 565)
    Dimension coordinates:
        projection_y_coordinate        -                       x                     -
        projection_x_coordinate        -                       -                     x
    Auxiliary coordinates:
        forecast_period                x                       -                     -
        height                         x                       -                     -
        time                           x                       -                     -
    Scalar coordinates:
        originating_centre: unknown centre lemm
```

So I would need to create a subset, or sub-cube. I have thought in iterating through all the cubes, looking for the temperature and adding it to a new cube.

So, how could I do it? And what could I use for the temperature if the typical Iris name, `air_ temperature` is not recognized? I think I should use WMO standard key for the temperature, `indicatorOfParameter = 11`, but how could I do it in Iris?